# Cómo acceder a mi partición Mac os X desde ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

acabo de instalar Ubuntu 20.04 sobre mi Macbook pro, hasta el momento todo bien, hasta que quise acceder a mis archivos de High sierra, como puedo hacer para poder acceder a mi disco duro?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Has instalado los paquetes de compatibilidad ?

```
sudo apt-get install hfsplus hfsutils hfsprogs
```

Encontré ésta página en que te van dando los pasos necesarios

[Montar unidad MAC OS X en Ubuntu](https://computrade-ec.com/blog/12-montar-particion-de-mac-os-x-en-linux)